# Workling worker cannot find newly added record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workling, starling-server

I'm using Starling and Workling to process background tasks in my application, a Swoopo-style auction site. In this case the background task is a notification system that monitors auctions and notifies the winner. The monitor is invoked upon creation of the auction object. My problem is that my monitoring code can't find the auction it's supposed to monitor. Here's the code:

The unit test that fails:

```
class AuctionTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "are monitored when created" do
    auction = Auction.new(
      :name => "A TV",
      :markdown => "A large TV",
      :starting_bid => 0.01,
      :bid_increment => 0.01,
      :starts_at => Time.now(),
      :ends_at => Time.now() + 5.seconds,
      :active => true
    )
    auction.save
    Bid.place(@current_user, auction)

    sleep(10) #when bids are placed, time is added to the end of the auction so wait

    assert auction.won?
    assert_equal @current_user.id, auction.winner_id
  end
end
```

The worker code:

```
class AuctionsWorker < Workling::Base
  def monitor(options)
    active = true
    ends_at = options[:original_ends_at]
    while active
      auction = Auction.find(options[:auction_id]) #this is the record that cannot be found
      if auction.won?
        active = false
        winner = User.find(auction.high_bidder).id
        auction.update_attribute(:winner_id, winner)
      else
        until Time.now() >= ends_at
          sleep(1)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The code that calls the worker:

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_create
    AuctionsWorker.asynch_monitor(:auction_id => self.id, :original_ends_at => self.ends_at) if self.active?
  end
end
```

Every time I run the test, I receive an error telling me that the auction supplied to the worker can't be found.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm using rails 2.3.5, sqlite3 and the latest Starling, Workling, and all other associated gems on a Mac OSX 10.6.2 Macbook Pro if it helps.

Thank you for all input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get downvoted for creating a "swoopo-style" auction, and I feel dirty for helping you.

> after_create()  Is called after
>   Base.save on new objects that haven‘t
>   been saved yet **(no record exists)**

so after_create is a bit of a misnomer - the record hasn't really been created yet.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M002142

You could add your own id field and have the workling process search the db for that id, sleeping a few seconds every time it doesn't find it (up to some preset failure limit).

Alternatively - you could try one of the several after_commit plugins that are on github that get called after the database has been updated.

Here's one:

http://github.com/delynn/after_commit

Comment: I don't exactly see the problem with these kinds of auctions as long as you don't mislead people when they sign up.

The error still occurs, however, and any other solutions would be greatly associated if I haven't offended you with my choice of application.

Comment: I've read that post before. I disagree with Atwood that these sites are illegal and the software equivalent of Satan himself. They're no more evil than any social gaming platform in my opinion, which is how I intend on marketing it.

I should've thought more before posting a question regarding this particular project on here though.

Comment: Auctions should promote efficiency, swoopo does not.  It's evil if you market it as a way to buy stuff at low prices.  The whole thing is set up to extract money from people who don't understand that they will overpay and likely get nothing.

Comment: Nonetheless, see above for a couple likely solutions.